# NestJS Typeorm entity type string template typescript

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'd like to use a typescript string template as the type of my class property like this:

```
type Path = `${string}/${string}`;

@Entity()
export class MyClass {
  @Column('text', { unique: true })
  path: Path;
}
```

But when I try I get this error message:

> TypeError: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance
> of Buffer or URL. Received undefined

Comment: ```const Path = `${string}/${string}`;``` should work

Comment: You should type it as `string` and add a CHECK constraint from database instead.